# Problems executing the Jupyter notebook using Sagemaker Lifecyle configuration

Tags: python, postgresql, jupyter-notebook, amazon-sagemaker, lifecycle

I have a set up a notebook in a sagemaker instance that collects data from a postgresql database and then updates a different one with the output. When running it manually, it works (I am using sqlalchemy's create_engine and then just using pandas' to_sql on the final dataframe).

I then set up a lifecycle configuration that would execute the notebook once the instance is triggered. I wanted to get around the 5-timeout issues so I used the nohup command when executing the notebook:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e
sudo -u ec2-user -i <<'EOF'

# PARAMETERS
ENVIRONMENT=python3
NOTEBOOK_FILE=/home/ec2-user/SageMaker/HourlyRun.ipynb

source /home/ec2-user/anaconda3/bin/activate "$ENVIRONMENT"

pip install --upgrade psycopg2-binary
pip install gensim==3.8.3

nohup jupyter nbconvert --to html "$NOTEBOOK_FILE" --ExecutePreprocessor.kernel_name=python3 --ExecutePreprocessor.timeout=-1 --execute &

source /home/ec2-user/anaconda3/bin/deactivate

# PARAMETERS
IDLE_TIME=1800

wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aws-samples/amazon-sagemaker-notebook-instance-lifecycle-config-samples/master/scripts/auto-stop-idle/autostop.py

if /usr/bin/python -c "import boto3" 2>/dev/null; then
    PYTHON_DIR='/usr/bin/python'
elif /usr/bin/python3 -c "import boto3" 2>/dev/null; then
    PYTHON_DIR='/usr/bin/python3'
else
    exit 1
fi

(crontab -l 2>/dev/null; echo "*/5 * * * * $PYTHON_DIR $PWD/autostop.py --time $IDLE_TIME --ignore-connections >> /var/log/jupyter.log") | crontab -

EOF
```

The instance now starts and stops as scheduled with no errors but I noticed the database wasn't being updated. I checked the logs and it seems like an operational error when querying the database.

[image]

I searched around for the solution but I only found references to changing hot_standby_feedback to "on" but it's not clear how I can do this within the code in jupyter. Not sure how approach this or if there is a better solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: From the logs, it doesn't look like a LCC issue. Have you seen this [best practice blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/best-practices-for-amazon-rds-postgresql-replication/#:~:text=Parameter%20settings%20at%20Read%20Replica)?

Comment: @durga_sury The parameters mentioned in that blog entry do come up as usual solutions for this error but I don't know how to access those and change them from within the script or the LCC because I am not directly managing the database. Alternatively is there a way to connect to it that goes around this problem? Not sure how to proceed here.